# Spectral minutiae MATLAB code

Tags: matlab, fingerprint

I am interested in fingerprint verification and I'm trying to implement spectral minutiae descriptors from [ref1].

[ref1] Xu, H., Veldhuis, R., Bazen, A. M., Kevenaar, T. A., Akkermans, T. A., & Gokberk, B. (2009). Fingerprint verification using spectral minutiae representations. Information Forensics and Security, IEEE Transactions on, 4(3), 397-409. (http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.353.1031)

This in my code function. I tested it on a short minutiae list, but results are very different than that published in [ref1]. I don't think that the problem is only parameter settings. I plotted both calculated and interpolated ML and MO descriptors, but images are very different.
Can anyone help me with the code?
My MATLAB code is:

```
function SpectralMinutiae
%minutie vector: xposition,yposition,orientation (30 minutiae)
minuVect= [50 75 -2.35619449019235;130 95 2.35619449019235;88 101 2.61799387799149;78 157 -2.35619449019235;189 172 -2.61799387799149;253 204 -2.35619449019235;118 217 2.61799387799149;116 229 -2.61799387799149;135 249 2.61799387799149;232 16 -0.523598775598299;193 25 -0.523598775598299;87 43 3.14159265358979;229 44 -0.523598775598299;64 64 -2.61799387799149;254 72 2.09439510239320;258 77 -1.57079632679490;138 83 0;230 86 2.35619449019235;40 116 0.785398163397448;206 126 -0.785398163397448;138 147 -1.04719755119660;137 163 2.09439510239320;227 173 -1.57079632679490;205 174 -2.09439510239320;162 176 -2.35619449019235;106 185 -1.57079632679490;243 187 -2.09439510239320;118 198 2.61799387799149;102 202 -1.04719755119660;163 211 -2.09439510239320];
%parameters
imageSize=300;
sigmaMG=3.2; %only for plot purposes
sigmaML=1; %0 from the paper
sigmaMO=4.25;
lambdaL=0.1;
lambdaH=0.6;

% plot minutiae in the spatial domain 
lx=linspace(1,imageSize,imageSize);   
[x,y]=meshgrid(lx,lx);  % //mesh
numMinu=size(minuVect,1);

z=MG(x,y,minuVect,numMinu,sigmaMG);
figure(1);
surf(x,y,z);shading interp;


%plot ML and MO functions (Fourier domain)
windowSize=5; 
flx=linspace(-windowSize,windowSize,300);
fly=linspace(-windowSize,windowSize,300);

[ux,uy]=meshgrid(flx,fly);  % //mesh
zML=ML(ux,uy,minuVect,numMinu,sigmaML);
figure(2);
imagesc(abs(zML)); title('Fourier Domain Image ML'); 

zMO=MO(ux,uy,minuVect,numMinu,sigmaMO);
figure(3);
imagesc(abs(zMO)); title('Fourier Domain Image MO'); 


%plot ML and MO functions in the Log-polar space

%In the radial direction M = 128 samples are used between lambdaL and lambdaH
%In the angular direction N = 256 samples are used between  0 and 2pi

rcoords = linspace(lambdaL,lambdaH,128);
thcoords = linspace(0,pi,256);
[ri,thi] = meshgrid(rcoords,thcoords);
[lx,ly] = pol2cart(thi,exp(ri)); 
figure(4);
z=ML(lx,ly,minuVect,numMinu,sigmaML);
imagesc(abs(z)); title('ML Polar coordinates'); 
figure(5);
z=MO(lx,ly,minuVect,numMinu,sigmaMO);
imagesc(abs(z)); title('MO Polar coordinates'); 

%plot ML and MO functions in the Log-polar space (obtained by interpolation)
z = interp2(ux,uy,zML,lx,ly);
figure(6);
imagesc(abs(z)); title('ML Polar coordinates (interpolated)'); 

z = interp2(ux,uy,zMO,lx,ly);
figure(7);
imagesc(abs(z)); title('MO Polar coordinates (interpolated)'); 

end

%Spatial domain function 
function z=MG(x,y,minuVect,numMinu,sigma)
    amplitude = 1.0 / (sigma * sqrt(2.0*pi));
    z = zeros(size(x));
    for j = 1:numMinu
         z= z + exp(-((x-minuVect(j,1)).^2+(y-minuVect(j,2)).^2)/( 2* sigma^2)) ;
    end;
    z=z.*amplitude;

end


%ML Fourier domain function 
function z=ML(ux,uy,minuVect,numMinu,sigma)
    z = zeros(size(ux));
    z = complex(z,0);
    for j = 1:numMinu
         z= z + exp(-1j*((ux*minuVect(j,1))+(uy*minuVect(j,2)))) ;
    end;
    den=-(sigma^(-2))*2;
    z=z.*exp((ux.^2+uy.^2)/den);   
end


%MO Fourier domain function 
function z=MO(ux,uy,mu,numMinuzie,sigma)
    z   = zeros(size(ux));
    z = complex(z,0);
    for j = 1:numMinuzie
         z= z + 1j*(ux*cos(mu(j,3))+uy*sin(mu(j,3))) .* exp(-1i*(ux*mu(j,1)+uy*mu(j,2))) ;
    end;
    z=z.*exp(-(ux.^2+uy.^2)/(2*(sigma^(-2))));

end
```

I think there is an error in functions ML and MO, but I can't find it. I wonder if someone would be kind enough to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the frequency term in your code? For fourier transform in your paper,you have to use omega term i.e. frequency term.

Comment: In Eq. 15 of [ref1] the omega term is denoted by omega_x and omega_y. In my code equation 15 is modeled by function ML(ux,uy,minuVect,numMinu,sigma) and the frequency terms are ux and uy. I think that it is ok, isn't it?

Comment: I think you are missing '-i' term(imaginary term) in spatial domain function.

Comment: Accordin to equation 14 in the [ref1], the spatial domain function (MG in my code) has not an immaginary part. 
MG is implemented according to equation 1 in [ref2].

[ref 2] Xu, Haiyun, and R. Veldhuis. "Complex spectral minutiae representation for fingerprint recognition." Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition Workshops (CVPRW), 2010 IEEE Computer Society Conference on. IEEE, 2010.